# Luigi: No such file or directory error when submitting a PySpark Task

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, luigi

Looking for help on this error and I'd really appreciate any advice on how to get past this.

As the subject says, I'm trying to run a very simple pyspark task but I'm getting "OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory"
.

In my working directory I have...

- luigi.cfg
- sparkLuigiTest.py

My config file contains...

```
[spark]
spark-submit:$SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-submit
master:yarn
num-executors:10
```

The *.py file contains...

```
import luigi
from luigi.contrib.spark import PySparkTask

class Test(PySparkTask):
    def input(self):
        return None

    def output(self):
        return luigi.LocalTarget("output.csv")

    def main(self, sc, *args):
        data = [(1,2,3), (4,5,6), (7,8,9)]
        data = sc.createDataFrame(data, ["A", "B", "C"])

        df = data.toPandas()
        df.to_csv("/u/<user name>/tests/luigi_woo.csv")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    luigi.run()
```

Lastly, I run my script with

```
LUIGI_CONFIG_PATH=./luigi.cfg python ./sparkLuigiTest.py --local-scheduler Test
```

Any ideas on why I'd be getting the following error?

```
ERROR: [pid 1678418] Worker Worker(salt=778216410, workers=1, host=hpchdp2e, username=<name>, pid=1678418) failed    Test()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/s/anaconda/users/<name>/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/luigi/worker.py", line 199, in run
    new_deps = self._run_get_new_deps()
  File "/s/anaconda/users/<name>/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/luigi/worker.py", line 141, in _run_get_new_deps
    task_gen = self.task.run()
  File "/s/anaconda/users/<name>/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/luigi/contrib/spark.py", line 309, in run
    super(PySparkTask, self).run()
  File "/s/anaconda/users/<name>/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/luigi/contrib/spark.py", line 66, in run
    super(SparkSubmitTask, self).run()
  File "/s/anaconda/users/<name>/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/luigi/contrib/external_program.py", line 134, in run
    with self._proc_with_tracking_url_context(proc_args=args, proc_kwargs=kwargs) as proc:
  File "/s/anaconda/users/<name>/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/contextlib.py", line 17, in __enter__
    return self.gen.next()
  File "/s/anaconda/users/<name>/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/luigi/contrib/external_program.py", line 168, in _proc_with_tracking_url_context
    main_proc = subprocess.Popen(proc_args, **proc_kwargs)
  File "/s/anaconda/users/<name>/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 394, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/s/anaconda/users/<name>/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1047, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Comment: Not directly related to your question (I think), but I'm curious, why are you using Python 2?

Comment: It's my employer's environment.  It's in the process of migrating

Comment: Is the environment involved in this at all, or do you only care about getting this example working?